# Compilers that compile `generic made up language X` into portable C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, terminology

I'm looking for two things. The first is a terminology.

What do we call compilers that compiles one language into another?

Secondly, are there any compilers that compile *generic made up language X* into portable C code?

I'm just throwing the idea out there, but I was thinking, what if we created our own front-end for a our own language of choice, but instead of going the whole way, the compiler emitted portable C code. This way, we could add new language features but still be very compatible with existing C code.

Now maybe there's a huge flaw in this approach (except that you need to build it) but do people do this?

Comment: I have recently been thinking a lot about these things too, but once you read a standard (for example C's), you realize there are so many pitfalls that it's very unlikely you would end up creating a _good_ language. Even C that we love so much has its dark corners. In reality, you should be able to make sure each feature is orthogonal to all the rest (something that is absolutely not true in C++, which is the reason why it has become the mess it is now)

Comment: You might want to look into [C--](http://www.cminusminus.org/), a C-like language designed specifically as a portable assembly language.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler . Have look a [Vala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)). It's exactly what you are describing.

Comment: great question but this should be on programmers.se

Answer (score 6):

People absolutely do this. In fact, the original implementation of C++ was a program called [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) that translated C++ into C code, to then be compiled with a C compiler.

With the prevalence today of intermediate "bytecode" languages such as JVM, CLR, and LLVM, translating languages to C source code is now much less common. It's much more powerful and less annoying to generate bytecode directly, rather than to generate textual source code. These bytecode (or "bitcode" in the case of LLVM) languages are lower level than textual programming languages, but still higher level than raw machine code that is tied to a specific CPU or CPU family.

I would call this sort of program a "translator", but that's just me. "Compiler" would work just fine too.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking about C++ all the time but completely forgot how C++ evolved in the first place. I have a follow up for you, have you ever had any troubles with ABIs on different platforms? Do you think a compiler like this could remedy a situation like that? Where the C ABIs are more stable and writing in a language with feature beyond C could be more portable, if it still was emitted as C?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any recent experience with distributing compiled code to different platforms. I tried to do that for Linux many years ago and it was a disaster (it's probably changed, but I just avoid going there).

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, if you stick with pure standard C, yes it would absolutely still be portable. If you need platform specific features, you probably would need to generate code with a lot of `ifdef`s

Comment: @GregHewgill We're targeting a wide verity of Linux distributions plus UNIX variants. We've been having a lot of issues with C++ ABIs but that's pretty much only on 10 year old distributions, I was thinking this could remedy that situation, somewhat.

Comment: @SK-logic: When I said "higher level", I meant higher level than machine code. Thanks, I'll clarify that.